# Как работать с несколькими страницами browser-sync?

Tags: gulp, npm, browsersync

На данный момент работаю с проектом который содержит много страниц, значит будет много `html` файлов со своими названиями, а `browser-sync` работает только с `index.html`, а если его нет, то выдает ошибку. Как правильно работать с многостраничными сайтами с помощью `browser-sync`?

Comment: Попробуй в url сам указать название страницы. Например: `localhost:3000/catalog.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было прописать в index адрес страницы с которой сейчас идет работа.

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "dest",
            index: "mainpage.html"
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenSever. разместите проект на локальном сервере и не нужно настраивать bs